# android passing data from fragment to adapter through bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, bundle, adapter

Im displaying data using cardview and have menuItem on cardview. Once the menu item is clicked Im opening a new fragment and want to pass the id as well(from respective card). I tried using different ways mentioned on internet but Im going wrong. Below is the code I used to send data from fragment to my adapter

```
  id = pobj.getString("id");
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CustomAdapter.class);
  intent.putExtra("id", id);
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Context mCtx;
private List<Mylist> names;
View view;
SharedPreferences preferences;
String id;
public CustomAdapter(View view,List<Mylist> names,Context mCtx) {
    this.names = names;
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.view =view;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
public void filterList(List<Mylist> filterdNames) {
    this.names = filterdNames;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Mylist mylist = names.get(position);

    holder.year.setText(mylist.getPurchase_year());
    holder.areatype.setText(mylist.getProperty_type());
    holder.area.setText(mylist.getSize());
holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {

            //will show popup menu here
            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
            //adding click listener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
 case R.id.menu_document:
                            //handle menu2 click
                            DocFragment newfragment1 = new DocFragment();
                    
final Intent intent = ((Activity) mCtx).getIntent();
                            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                            if(bundle != null){
                                id = bundle.getString("id");
                            }


                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 =((AppCompatActivity)mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container_view1, newfragment1);
                            fragmentTransaction1.addToBackStack(null);
                            fragmentTransaction1.commit();
                            NavigationActivity.container_view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to pass data from Activity (or outside of Fragment) to Fragment :

**1- Set arguments to the fragment**

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.setString("id", id);
newfragment1.setArguments(args);
```

**2- Using newInstance function**

create an static method in your DocFragment :

```
public static DocFragment newInstance(String id) {
    DocFragment docFragment = new DocFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("id", id);
    docFragment.setArguments(args);
    return docFragment;
}
```

then change initialization of the fragment to :

```
String id = bundle.getString("id"); //after retrieving from extras
DocFragment newfragment1 = DocFragment.newInctance(id);
```

after passing data to the fragment you can retrieve the arguments on the method onCreate or onCreateView of your frgament :

```
 Bundle args = getArguments();
 int index = args.getString("id");
```

Comment: I updated the above code but still not getting the ID..

Comment: How do you retrieve your data in the fragment, Did you use logcat to find out if arguments passed truly?

Comment: I changed the approach since the app was getting crashed. But thank you